# Should a taunt, which is grammatically correct as a question, be treated like a question or a taunt

Tags: questions

I am confused if a question which is placed like a taunt can be taken like a question or like a taunt.

Examples:

> - Are you saying so because you built it?
> - Is it too much to ask for?

These are grammatically correct questions, but do they sound provoking? Are these necessarily questions, not just grammatically but the way they sound?

Comment: Rhetorical questions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Punctuate taunting questions as questions. To do otherwise would be odd and unclear. The rhetorical, taunting meaning comes through loud and clear.

Comment: When you say 'grammatically correct questions' I assume you mean possessing this structure: "Is it after twelve yet?" Modern practice is veering towards omitting the question marks from similarly-structured requests: "Would you please shut the door, Bill." but including it in declarative questions: "You think I'm kidding you?"

Comment: @EdwinAshworth : Yes , I was talking about the structure.